# Use a while loop to increase font

Tags: javascript

I was tasked with doing a loop that increase the font size of a text when it makes an iteration.
I don't know where to start because you can't use px or font-size on the loop.

I made this code, but I don't even know where to start. This is the code

```js
function aumentar() {
  document.getElementById("parrafo")
  contador = 5;
  while (contador <= 15) {
    contador++;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="parrafo">Este es el texto de prueba</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried [searching for other question about how to change font-size using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change+font+size+javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really help understand why you would want something like this, but here's how you would set the font size based on the value of "contador".

```
element.style.fontSize = `${contador}px`;
```

Where `element` is the actual DOM element to be modified. and the ` ` is used to write [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). This is how you can use "px" inside javascript.

The example below has a higher value in the `while` loop - just so you can visually see the font size change.

Ofcourse, when you execute this - you will only see the final result. You will have to add some sort of sleep mechanism to actually see it growing. This method is not ideal and you shouldn't be trying to do it this way (unless you know exactly what you're doing).

```js
function aumentar() {
  let element = document.getElementById("parrafo");
  let contador = 5;

  while (contador <= 50) {
    contador++;
    element.style.fontSize = `${contador}px`;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', aumentar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="parrafo">Este es el texto de prueba</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**A better solution** -

I'd recommend a pure CSS animation based solution that will use the `font-size` property to take 'X' seconds to increase the font-size. It will also use the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to make sure the final font-size is retained by the element being resized.

I'm adding another snippet with the CSS based example.

```css
#parrafo {
  font-size: 10px;
  animation: text-grow 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes text-grow {
  from {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="parrafo">Este es el texto de prueba</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you should put more emphasis on the integer-string concatenation and how  styling  in JS works than doing his homework 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/1893976

Comment: @Felix You're right. I've updated the answer to have some more info on template literals with the MDN link. It makes a lot of sense that this is a homework question.